# How to print specific key and value from map in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map, and I need to get a specific key and value.

I've tried using a for loop, but that doesn't seem to solve my problems.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0, "$");
map.put(0, "|");
map.put(0, "*");
```

I need to get the key and value of a specific item. For example, I need to get just the key and value of `money`, and not of anything else.

Comment: Sorry, I put the code fencing wrong. Should be fixed now.

Comment: That isn't valid code. What do you mean the specific key and value of `money`? What do you think `String money = map.put(0, "$");` should do? As best I can tell, you want a `String` key (e.g. "money") and then a tuple value (e.g. `Integer`, `String`).

Comment: Now your `map` only contains one entry. `0, "*"`.

Comment: I made the variable money so that I can save the values of ```money```. I just want to get the key and value of ```money``` only.

Comment: If I remove the variables, how can I get the get the keys and values?

Comment: All of the keys of the map are 0, so how will I get the correct keys and values?

Comment: There is only one key in the map. `0`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Am I supposed to switch the keys and values?

Comment: What do you mean by `money`?

Comment: Switching the keys and values would _work_, but maybe only in the sense that you'd now have a map with key/value pairs of ["$", 0], ["|", 0], ["*",0].  It's up to you to decide if such a map is helpful to you for your particular application.

Comment: Seems you have no clue what a map is and how it works. **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), which starts by saying: *"An object that maps keys to values. **A map cannot contain duplicate keys**; each key can map to at most one value."* --- Or you could read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) on the topic. --- Or do a web search. There are many articles to be found there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A Map cannot contain duplicate keys but can contain duplicate values.**

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(0, "$");
map.put(1, "|");
map.put(2, "*");
for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> m: map.entrySet()) {
    if(m.getValue().equals("$")) {
        System.out.println(m.getKey() + ":" + m.getValue());
    }           
}
```

Output :

```
0:$
```